# Setting a default value for a radio input in a transcluded, isolated directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

Okay, I know the title sounds a bit complex. I'll try to explain what I am attempting:

I have a modal dialog directive (based on [this tutorial](http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/) which uses transclusion to wrap the stuff I want to show in the dialog:

```
.directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'directives/modalDialog.tpl.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.hideModal = function() {
                scope.show = false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I am invoking the directive in my view like so:

```
<modal-dialog show="showSaveDialog">
<form role="form" name="saveForm" ng-submit="save()">
    Name:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true"><br>

    <input type="radio" ng-model="isPublic" id="public-true" value="true" ng-required="true"> Make Public.<br>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="isPublic" id="public-false" value="false" ng-required="true"> Make Private.<br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="saveForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
</modal-dialog>
```

The `showSaveDialog` is just a property on the controller's scope that is set to `true` when I want to display the dialog.

### Problem

It all works fine except for the fact that **I want to make the radio buttons default to "public"**.

Since the radio buttons are bound by `ng-model` to the `isPublic` property, I am at a loss as to how I can specify `isPublic = true` when the modal is displayed.

On the transcluded scope, the `isPublic` property does not initially exist. Therefore both of the radio buttons are unselected. The property is only created once one of the radio buttons is checked.

### Attempted solutions

I have tried to following, to no avail:

- using `ng-init` in the transcluded HTML to set `isPublic = true`. Strangely, I can see that the transcluded scope *does* have `isPublic` set to `true`, yet the radio buttons both remain unchecked. Perhaps this is due to the order in which things happen when compiling and linking the scope to the template. Beyond that, it seems like a disgusting hack to use `ng-init`.
- Setting the `isPublic` property to `true` on the controller's scope. This does not work, even when I do it as an object property, i.e. (on the controller) `$scope.model.isPublic = true` and then setting the radio button `ng-model=model.isPublic`.
- using the HTML `checked` attribute on the input I want as the default. It seems it gets overwritten or ignored by Angular in favour of the data-bound model.

I suspect that the problem may be that I am approaching this in the wrong way. But the rest of the directive works so nicely, so I hope someone can help me find a solution to what I want to do!